# Google Appscript- Combine data from 2 different tabs from a Gsheet into master Gsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to combine data from 2 different tabs (copy and paste from 'track1' tab, then below it copy and paste from 'track2) but my script just return from 1 tab.

Process is:

1. Copy from 'track1' of 'Gsheetxx'
2. Paste into this master sheet
3. Then copy from 'track2' of 'Gsheetxx'
4. Paste it below 'track1' data

Below is my script:

```
    /** COPY AND PASTE FROM DASHBOARD TO MASTER SHEET **/
function copypaste(){

  // get the name of today's tab
  var fileName = '[Track1]'
  var fileName2 = '[Track2]'
  Logger.log(fileName); 

  // copy of track data-copy from 'track1' and 'track2' tab
  var fileID = 'Gsheetxx'
  var sheetDash = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID);
  var sheetDash2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID);
  var tabDash = sheetDash.getSheetByName(fileName);
  var tabDash2 = sheetDash2.getSheetByName(fileName2);
  var lastRowDash = my_getLastRow(tabDash,"A:AI");
  var lastRowDash = my_getLastRow(tabDash2,"A:AI");
  var rangeDash = tabDash.getRange("A2:AI" + lastRowDash);
  var rangeDash2 = tabDash2.getRange("A2:AI" + lastRowDash);  
  var valuesDash = rangeDash.getValues();
  var valuesDash2 = rangeDash2.getValues();

  // paste in current master tab
  var tabIngest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("ingestion");
  var clearRangeIngest = tabIngest.getRange("A2:AJ"); 
  var rangeIngest = tabIngest.getRange("B2:AJ" + lastRowDash);
  clearRangeIngest.clearContent();
  rangeIngest.setValues(valuesDash);


// paste in current master tab
  var tabIngest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("ingestion");
  var clearRangeIngest = tabIngest.getRange("A2:AJ"); 
  var rangeIngest = tabIngest.getRange("B2:AJ" + lastRowDash);
  clearRangeIngest.clearContent();
  rangeIngest.setValues(valuesDash2);

}

/** GET LAST ROW **/
function my_getLastRow(sheet,rangeString) {
  var lr_rng = sheet.getRange(rangeString).getValues();
  var lrIndex;
    
  for(var i = lr_rng.length-1; i>=0; i--){
      lrIndex = i;
    if(!lr_rng[i].every(function(c){return c == "";})){
    break;
    }
  }
  return lrIndex + 1;
}
```

Comment: because you clear the content after pasting the first tab by `clearRangeIngest.clearContent();` twice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
// paste in current master tab
var tabIngest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("ingestion");
var clearRangeIngest = tabIngest.getRange("A2:AJ"); 
var rangeIngest = tabIngest.getRange("B2:AJ" + lastRowDash);
clearRangeIngest.clearContent();
rangeIngest.setValues(valuesDash);


// paste in current master tab
var tabIngest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("ingestion");
var clearRangeIngest = tabIngest.getRange("A2:AJ"); 
var rangeIngest = tabIngest.getRange("B2:AJ" + lastRowDash);
clearRangeIngest.clearContent();
rangeIngest.setValues(valuesDash2);
```

#### To:

```
var values = [...valuesDash, ...valuesDash2];
var tabIngest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("ingestion");
tabIngest.getRange("A2:AJ").clearContent();
tabIngest.getRange(2, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

- In this modification, the values of `valuesDash` and `valuesDash2` are merged and put to the sheet.

As another approach, when Sheets API is used, the values can be retrieved from the several sheets by one API call. Using this, your script is as follows. If you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function copypaste() {
  var fileName = '[Track1]';
  var fileName2 = '[Track2]';
  var fileID = 'Gsheetxx';

  // 1. Retrieve values from 2 sheets in 'Gsheetxx'.
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(fileID, {ranges: [fileName, fileName2].map(f => `'${f}'!A2:AI`)}).valueRanges.flatMap(e => e.values.filter(r => r.join("") != ""));

  // 2. Put the values to "ingestion" sheet in the active Spreadsheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tabIngest = ss.getSheetByName("ingestion");
  tabIngest.getRange("A2:AJ").clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values}, ss.getId(), "'ingestion'!B2", {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
}
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: Hi I've tried the API call approached and it works! But then I have another problem as the data is too big, giving the error HttpResponseException: Response Code: 413. Message: response too large. You know how can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: @Kreng Kongkeng Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `But then I have another problem as the data is too big, giving the error HttpResponseException: Response Code: 413. Message: response too large. You know how can I solve it?`, although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet, if the data is over the limitation of the Spreadsheet, an error occurs. This is the current specification. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. At that time, please reduce the data and test it again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Hey don't say that. You helped me.. Yup it works fine with lesser data! First I tried with ~30k and 200 rows of "Track" data it works fine. But then when i tried with both "Track" sheet with 30k rows, it prompted the error. Is okay, just asking if you have idea how to solve it.

Comment: @Kreng Kongkeng Thank you for replying. I thought that from your reply, in this case, reducing the data size might be a workaround. I apologize that I cannot propose more workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

#### insert into master tab

```
function copypaste() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Gsheetxx');
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('[Track1]');
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('[Track2]');
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange(2, 1, sh1.getLastRow() - 1, 35).getValues();
  const vs2 = sh2.getRange(2, 1, sh2.getLastRow() - 1, 35).getValues();
  let a = [];
  a.push(vs1);
  a.push(vs2);
  a.flat(1);
  const msh = ss.getSheetByName("ingestion");
  msh.getRange(2,2,a.length,a[0].length).setValues(q)
}
```